# Tests not running - Postgres database not connect via circle ci

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, circleci

I am running a Django project and I have set up tests and wanted to run them through circle ci. However, when I push my code to GitHub. Circle CI can't seem to connect the database. This only started when I introduced a .env file and python decouple

What is the best way to setup  environment variables  that I need for development and the same time for Circle CI?

I have tried creating seperate settings config files. I have tried creating environment variables on the  CircleCI dashboard  but Circle CI is still not able to connect to the db and it seems like the environment variables are causing the error but I am not sure why?

To see the error. Click here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/swVfK.png.

You can also clone my project from github to test it  out yourself and also to check out my config.yml

[Github Repo](https://github.com/arondasamuel123/turf4u-api)

I would really appreciate some insight on this

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. The issue had to do with the HOST, CircleCI couldn't tell which HOST I was using  so I had to specify HOST env variable in my project and CircleCI Dashboard

```
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
```

For some strange reason to totally solve the issue is to use dj-database-url and have a single DATABASE_URL. I haven't tested this yet though.

I hope this helps someone in case they stumble into the same problem

Comment: As far as I'm concerned just adding `'HOST': 'localhost'` in settings.py DATABASES definition made it work.